# Pandas not reading tables from html files in folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to read the tables of each individual html file in a folder using pandas, to find out the number of tables in each file.

However, this feature works when specifying a single file, but when I try to run it in the folder it says there are no tables.

This is the code for the single file

```
import pandas as pd


file = r'C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\Desktop\XXX.html'
table = pd.read_html(file)

print ('tables found:', len(table))
```

This is the output

```
C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe C:/Users/Ahmed_Abdelmuniem/PycharmProjects/PandaHTML/main.py
tables found: 72

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This is the code for each file in a folder

```
import pandas as pd
import shutil
import os

source_dir = r'C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\Desktop\TMorning'
target_dir = r'C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\Desktop\TAfternoon'

file_names = os.listdir(source_dir)

for file_name in file_names:
    table = pd.read_html(file_name)
    print ('tables found:', len(table))
```

This is the error log:

```
C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe "C:/Users/Ahmed_Abdelmuniem/PycharmProjects/File mover V2.0/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\PycharmProjects\File mover V2.0\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    table = pd.read_html(file_name)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1085, in read_html
    return _parse(
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 913, in _parse
    raise retained
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 893, in _parse
    tables = p.parse_tables()
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 213, in parse_tables
    tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 543, in _parse_tables
    raise ValueError("No tables found")
ValueError: No tables found

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.listdir` returns a list containing the names of the entries in the directory including subdirectories or any other files. If you want to keep only html files, prefer use `glob.glob`.

```
import glob

file_names = glob.glob(os.path.join(source_dir, '*.html'))
```

**Edit**: if you want to use `os.listdir`, you have to get the actual path to the file:

```
for file_name in file_names:
    table = pd.read_html(os.path.join(source_dir, file_name))
    print ('tables found:', len(table))
```

Comment: Thanks a million bud, it worked. But why didn't it work if the only files are html files?